# How to find out if the webpage loads slow because of a slow server?

Tags: webserver

A web-development company made us a website on Wordpress. The website runs really really slow on our server. They say that our server is slow. We say that their code is not optimized.

How to probe or test or see if our server is slow? What metrics to look for? What to look for to see if our server is a bottleneck? What tests to run?

Our server runs on CentOS, Apache 2.4, php 8.1, MySQL 5.7.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't enabled PHP caching.

Comment: `valgrind` is one possible tool. Google `valgrind php profiling` for additional suggestions.